# React Router Re-render when go back not using redux

Tags: reactjs, typehead

I don't want to re-render the component if the customer goes and back from a browser or pressing back button from web app. Please help me with this. I am stuck, You can view the functionality from the [link](https://www.myrentalcar.com/v3/search_booking.php?country_des=133&pick_up=14583&pick_up_hour=10&pick_up_minute=00&country_drop=133&drop_off=14583&drop_off_hour=10&drop_off_minute=00&country_chk=on&country=163&age_chk=on&age_driver=30&pickupdates=07-04-2020&dropoffdates=14-04-2020&discount_code=&shwtrw=&is_airport=4&city=Bugibba&fromemail=&country_des=133&country_drop=133&car_group_type=all&pick_up_day=07&pick_up_mon=04&pick_up_year=2020&drop_off_day=14&drop_off_mon=04&drop_off_year=2020&lan=en&only_trw=&currency=PKR&book_log_id=25432532&filter_car_id=#search_booking)

Also if change pickup location with typehead, it cannot change in drop locations as typehead not changed the default value.

Comment: *You can view the functionality from the link* I clicked the link, how can I view the functionality?

Comment: Edit your question and add some more details with more explanation, or the question will be closed as the low-quality question.

Comment: give me time, i will update the functionality on the site. Only problem when customer click on price button and goest to next screen , and then back from next screen , it re render all the componennt.

Comment: import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Book from "./components/book/book";
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";
const customHistory = createHistory();


const CustomeRouter = props => (
  <Router history={customHistory}>
    {console.log(props)}
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/book/" component={Book} />
      <Route path="/" component={App} oldProps= {props} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default CustomeRouter;

Comment: When you click the back button, and some component appears, it re-mounts. And still, if you don't want it to happen, use a dialog box as it does not unmount the screen in the background.

Comment: need smilar like [link](https://www.rentalcargroup.com/v2/search_booking.php?country_des=133&pick_up=14583&pick_up_hour=10&pick_up_minute=00&country_drop=133&drop_off=14583&drop_off_hour=10&drop_off_minute=00&country_chk=on&country=163&age_chk=on&age_driver=30&pickupdates=07-04-2020&dropoffdates=14-04-2020&discount_code=&shwtrw=&is_airport=4&city=Bugibba&fromemail=&country_des=133&country_drop=133&car_group_type=all&pick_up_day=07&pick_up_mon=04&pick_up_year=2020&drop_off_day=14&drop_off_mon=04&drop_off_year=2020&lan=en&only_trw=&currency=PKR&book_log_id=25432532&filter_car_id=#search_booking)

Comment: sir Siraj please check my below answer (not answer but question more clear) . Please help me

Comment: I've added a comment in your answer below;.

Comment: Is it actually rerendering, or is it just redisplaying the cached version from the router's history stack when you navigate back? If any of the route props or any of the other props have changed, then ofc it will rerender the component. What are `oldProps`? The `Switch` OFC only mounts a single matching route at a time though. Is there an issue with it rendering again?

Comment: i was trying to figure it out put oldprops , oldProps is not used, just need a solution , i dont want to re-render again.  Send me the code please that will not re-render or any other solution rather than router.

Answer (score 0):

I did by show hide div above the component in render functions like below

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import App from "./App";
 import Book from "./components/book/book";

class Root extends Component {
  state = { page: "searchBooking" };
  changePage = page => {
    this.setState({ page: page });
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let obj = this;
    window.addEventListener(
      "hashchange",
      function() {
        //console.log("The hash has changed!");
        if (window.location.hash === "#book") {
          obj.setState({ page: "book" });
        } else {
          obj.setState({ page: "search" });
        }
        return;
      },
      true
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            display:
              this.state.page === "searchBooking" ||
              this.state.page === "search"
                ? "block"
                : "none"
          }}
        >
          <App changePage={this.changePage} page={this.state.page} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: this.state.page === "book" ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <Book changePage={this.changePage} page={this.state.page} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```